# I want to assign User Assigned managed Identity to VMSS created in MC resource group through Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I want to assign User Assigned managed Identity to VMSS created in MC resource group so that all the pods created in K8S have access to associated Key Vault.
I have done it through powershell script, Here's the Script:

```
 $aksNodeVmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "$aksMcRg"
 Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $aksMcRg -Name $aksNodeVmss.Name -IdentityType UserAssigned -IdentityID $id
```

But I want to do it in Terraform but I'm unable to find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

The VMSS identity is the kubelet identity of your nodepool. AKS nowadays supporting "bring your own" kubelet identity while creating the cluster, so no need for updating the identities.

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "kubelet" {
  name                = "uai-kubelet"
  location            = <YOUR_LOCATION>
  resource_group_name = <YOUR_RG>
}


resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "aks" {
  name                = "uai-aks"
  location            = <YOUR_LOCATION>
  resource_group_name = <YOUR_RG>
}

# This can be also a custom role with Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/assign/action allowed
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "this" {
  scope                = <YOUR_RG>
  role_definition_name = "Managed Identity Operator"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks.principal_id
}
```

Then assign the identity to the kublet:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  ...

   identity {
     type = "UserAssigned"
     identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aks.id]
  } 

  kubelet_identity {
    client_id                 = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.client_id
    object_id                 = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.principal_id
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But I got error on it:
Here's the error:
 Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kc,
│   on kubernetesCluster.tf line 62, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kc":
│   62:   client_id                 = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi.client_id
│ 
│ "kubelet_identity.0.client_id": all of
│ `identity.0.identity_ids,kubelet_identity.0.client_id,kubelet_identity.0.object_id,kubelet_identity.0.user_assigned_identity_id`
│ must be specified

Comment: This only works with a user-assigned managed cluster. I updated the code.